Implementing SHAKE using SHA3
I have a implementation of SHA3-256 and SHA3-512 in C as API's below
sha3_256(output, input, inputlen)
sha3_512(output, input, inputlen)

I want to now implement SHAKE128 and SHAKE256 using these API's. Is that possible and if so, how ?
I don't have access to the internal functions of the above API's, they are available to me as function pointers.

If there's upper/lower layer distinction, then code space / circuit length can be saved - upper layer for hashing API and sponge construction, lower layer for the Keccak permutation.

This is not possible.
For SHAKE128 this is trivially true, because there is no normal SHA3 hash function which has the same "capacity" (~internal state size), as we can see in section 6 of the SHA-3 specification, where the capacity defined for each function is indicated between the [brackets]:
SHA3-224(M) = KECCAK[448] (M || 01, 224);
SHA3-256(M) = KECCAK[512] (M || 01, 256);
SHA3-384(M) = KECCAK[768] (M || 01, 384);
SHA3-512(M) = KECCAK[1024](M || 01, 512)

SHAKE128(M, d) = KECCAK[256] (M || 1111, d),
SHAKE256(M, d) = KECCAK[512] (M || 1111, d).

For SHAKE256, SHA3-256 does have the same capacity, and the functions are very similar. However, SHAKE256 is not constructed from instances of SHA3-256. It's constructed from repeating the the "squeezing" step of the SHA3's sponge construction until the desired number of bits have been generated. It's not possible to obtain the internal state from this output (that would violate the security properties of the algorithm), so it's not possible to take a SHA3-256 output and use it to produce a longer SHAKE256 output for the same input.
If that was all that was going on, it would at least be possible to take a SHA3-256 output and truncate it to produce a SHAKE256 output of up to 256 bits, but there's another major element which prevents that: domain separation.
It is considered undesirable for two different algorithms to produce the same output, even if their internal structure is identical. In the case of SHA-3, this property is ensured by appending a distinct suffix to the input indicating the mode that the algorithm is operating in, before generating any output. In the function specifications above, we can see that that for normal SHA3 hash functions, the suffix is the bits 01, while for SHAKE functions it is the bits 1111. This also is mentioned in section 6 of the specification:

The bolded suffix (i.e., 11) supports domain separation: it distinguishes the inputs to KECCAK[c] that arise from RawSHAKE128 and RawSHAKE256 from the inputs arising from the SHA3 hash functions defined in Sec. 6.1, as well as other domains that may be defined in the future.

Therefore it is not possible to produce any bits of a SHAKE digest if the only thing you have to work with are complete instances of normal SHA3 hash functions.

(It's the "SHA-3" specification/family, but the functions themselves are named starting with "SHA3". I'm not sure if I've hyphenated correctly through this answer.)

it is just beauty of SHA-3-224 vs SHA3-224

but say, i am able to somehow get internal state of sha3 after every operation, would it be possible then ? i can then adjust the padding to get shake output ?

assuming i am working on a hw accelerator and have access to internal states

@Gappu It might be possible, depending on what details and operations are exposed. I haven’t used any system like you describe before, so I’m not sure.

thanks Jeremy. you have been really helpful. cheers
